# How do I use properties in ants replace task?

Tags: ant, replace

I need to replace a token with a property. That property has a path location set. I am not getting it as it is just replacing it with the $

```
<replace file="${APACHE_HOME}/conf/wc_server1.conf" >
  <replacetoken>@Install_Base_Directory@</replacetoken> 
<replacevalue>$InstallerBase</replacevalue>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options:

```
<replace file="${APACHE_HOME}/conf/wc_server1.conf" >
  <replacetoken><![CDATA[@Install_Base_Directory@]]></replacetoken> 
  <replacevalue><![CDATA[$InstallerBase]]></replacevalue>
</replace>
```

or since it's only a single line replace, use:

```
<replace file="${APACHE_HOME}/conf/wc_server1.conf" 
  token="@Install_Base_Directory@"
  value="$InstallerBase" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Ant [properties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties) you must enclose the property name in curlies `{...}` to get at the value:

```
<replacevalue>${InstallerBase}</replacevalue>
```