# ANT "replace" task not expanding properties in "replacetoken" tag

Tags: ant, replace

After build, I need to modify an HTML file that points the client to download the new app.

I search for a token; replace it with a link and token:

```
<replace file="index.html" >

    <!-- this searches for literal text ${MyTOKEN} -->
    <!-- does not "expand" ${MyTOKEN} before searching -->
    <replacetoken>${MyTOKEN}</replacetoken>

    <replacevalue>"some link" <br> ${MyTOKEN}</replacevalue>
</replace>
```

---

This code CANNOT be moved into a template build script because the `replacetoken` and `replacevalue` tags take the text as literals - they do not `expandproperties` in my version of ANT.

I would like to use properties to define the `"some link"` and `MyTOKEN` values.

---

Workaround for using properties in `"some link"` is to use a `filterchain` and copy the file after the replacement:

```
<copy file="index.html" tofile="index2.html" >
    <filterchain>
        <!-- this converts the ${xxx} properties into their values -->
        <expandproperties />
    </filterchain>
</copy>
```

But that works AFTER the `replace` has been done - so it means I still need to hard-code the `MyTOKEN` values directly into the build script.

- I want to **define my token outside** of my build script, and **reference it inside** the build script.
- How do I do that?

---

**Update:** Should I create my own `replace` task using `copy`, `filterreader` and `filterchain`? I don't really understand that method properly, but it looks like the way.

---

**Update expanding on accepted answer:** I was originally using the `<replacetoken>` & `<replacevalue>` method because I needed my value to span multiple lines.

By using `token` & `value`, I was unable to find a way to make line breaks.

The solution to putting line breaks is to use `${line.separator}` as the line break. See docs on the [Echo Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).

As an extra, here is a page of some more useful (off topic) ANT properties: [Built-in Ant Properties](http://www.ghidinelli.com/2008/04/01/built-in-ant-properties).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use properties in ants replace task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216462/how-do-i-use-properties-in-ants-replace-task) but the answers don't work for me

Comment: trying to get these solutions to work, but don't understand them properly: [Ant replace token from properties file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680362/ant-replace-token-from-properties-file) & [Simulating the Maven2 filter mechanism using Ant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233820/383414)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `token` and `value` attributes works here. This works for me with Ant 1.7.1:

build.properties

```
token=FOO
tokval=some ${token}
```

build.xml

```
<project>
  <property file="build.properties" />
  <target name="repl">
    <replace file="test.txt" token="${token}" value="${tokval}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiline replacement with markers where the properties need to go: `@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@`

```
     <replace dir="${dir_build_docs_javadoc}">
        <replacetoken><![CDATA[</head>]]></replacetoken>
       <replacevalue><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<!-- Required for syntax highlighting (1/2)...START -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@resources/shCore.js"></script>
  <link href="@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@resources/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@resources/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@resources/shBrushJava.js"></script>
<!-- Required for syntax highlighting (1/2)...END -->
</HEAD>]]></replacevalue>
     </replace>
```

And then run another single line replacement for the properties:

```
<target name="-replace_all_javadoc_headers">
   <antcall target="-javadoc_replace_headers_in_one_dir">
     <param name="directory_to_replace" value="${dir_build_docs_javadoc}"/>
     <param name="relative_url_to_doc_root" value=""/>
   </antcall>
   <antcall target="-javadoc_replace_headers_in_one_dir">
     <param name="directory_to_replace" value="${dir_build_docs_javadoc}${cg_xbn_codelet}"/>
     <param name="relative_url_to_doc_root" value="../../../../"/>
   </antcall>
   <antcall target="-javadoc_replace_headers_in_one_dir">
     <param name="directory_to_replace" value="${dir_build_docs_javadoc}${cg_xbn_codelet}type${fs}"/>
     <param name="relative_url_to_doc_root" value="../../../../../"/>
   </antcall>
   <antcall target="-javadoc_replace_headers_in_one_dir">
     <param name="directory_to_replace" value="${dir_build_docs_javadoc}${cg_xbn_codelet}taglet${fs}"/>
     <param name="relative_url_to_doc_root" value="../../../../../"/>
   </antcall>
</target>

<target name="-javadoc_replace_headers_in_one_dir">
  <replace dir="${directory_to_replace}" 
        token="@__relative_url_to_doc_root__@" 
        value="${relative_url_to_doc_root}">
     <include name="*.html"/>
  </replace>
```